# How would i write a test for something which uses stdout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, bunyan

I'm trying to improve test coverage on this file

```
'use strict'

/**
 * Returns the logging options we're using
 *
 * @param   {String} name Name of the logger. Should be service name. e.g. ciitizen-file-service
 * @returns {Object}      The logging options we're using
 * @private
 */
function getLoggerOptions(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    streams: [
      {
        level: 'info',
        stream: stdOutStream()
      }, {
        level: 'error',
        stream: stdErrStream()
      }
      , {
        level: 'debug',
        stream: stdOutStream()
      },
      {
        level: 'warn',
        stream: stdOutStream()
      },
      {
        level: 'fatal',
        stream: stdErrStream()
      }
    ]
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a stream that writes to stdout
 *
 * @param   {Object} info The log info
 * @returns {Object}      An object which logs to stdout
 * @private
 */
function stdOutStream() {
  return {
    write: log => {
      // Change log level number to name and write it out
      log.level = bunyan.nameFromLevel[log.level]
      process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(log) + '\n')
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a stream that writes to stderr
 *
 * @param   {Object} info The log info
 * @returns {Object}      An object which logs to stderr
 * @private
 */
function stdErrStream() {
  return {
    write: log => {
      // Change log level number to name and write it out
      log.level = bunyan.nameFromLevel[log.level]
      process.stderr.write(JSON.stringify(log) + '\n')
    }
  }
}

module.exports = { getLoggerOptions }
```

I currently have this test

```
'use strict'

const expect = require('chai').expect
const { getLoggerOptions } = require('../src/helpers')

describe.only('#getLoggerOptions', () => {
  it('should return the logger options', () => {
    expect(getLoggerOptions('test')).to.be.an('object')
  })
})
```

Which produces this gap in unit test coverage [image]

How can i write a test to cover this code?

Comment: Try to use stubs (`sinon.stub`) to test such functionality. Create stub and test that stubbed function was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only asserting that `getLoggerOptions(...)` should returns an object, but you are not accessing the object.

For instance, apart from the posted test, try adding a test like:

```
describe.only('#probeLoggerOptions', () => {
  it('should do expected logging stuff', () => {
    const {name, streams} = getLoggerOptions('test');
    for (let stream of streams) {
      console.log(`getting logopt for level ${stream.level}`);
      expect(stream.stream.write(log), /* ... what to expect */);
    }
  });
});
```

Now the test is calling the `write` function in each object.

**EXTRA**: If you own the code, the best way is to refactor it to be more testable. For instance, instead of writing to high-level `process` streams directly, you might create a `WritableStream`, write to it, then pipe to the desired `process` stream.

```
function configureStream(writable = process.stdout, data = null, msg = 'done') {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/log');
  stream.read(data);
  stream.pipe(writable);
```

}

```
function stdOutStream() {
  return {
    write: log => {
      // Change log level number to name and write it out
      log.level = bunyan.nameFromLevel[log.level];
      configureStream(data = JSON.stringify(log) + '\n');
    }
  }
}
```

Apart from being able to test `configureStream` separately, you could also abstract the meat of each logging process to one function that reduce the test surface. Now you could also hook into stream's events like 'pipe' or 'finish' to check the content being logged.

Comment: Your first example fails b/c log is undefined `expect(stream.write(log)`

Comment: When i change it to `expect(stream.write('foo'))` I now get the error `TypeError: stream.write is not a function`

Comment: @Catfish `log` was not provided because I had no knowledge of it. You should be able to provide that yourself.

Comment: Excuse me, the `stream` here was an object with properties `level` and `stream`, thus you have to call `stream.stream.write(log)`. I corrected it.

Comment: I"m trying to follow your "extra", but your code doesn't work. You can't create a write stream like that. You need to pass a string or a buffer. I changed it to ` const myStream = fs.createWriteStream('foobar')
    myStream.write('foo')
    myStream.pipe(myStream)
    myStream.end()` and I now get the error `Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable`

Comment: @Catfish I apologize but I didn't really have access to Nodejs to test out the EXTRA bit. Apart from EXTRA did the main question get answered though?

Comment: Yep it sure did